# How to filter view by actual name of logged in user matches field?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 and latest Views. I have a static field set with a variety of names, for a specific view I want to filter if the name of the logged in user matches the actual name of logged in user.

For example if logged in user is "Jean Claude" and I have a field with:

Big Sky,
Orange Cat,
Jean Claude

I would only want to display the content the field set to Jean Claude.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post: [Views: Filtering nodes on the basis of logged in user role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70284/views-filtering-nodes-on-the-basis-of-logged-in-user-role?rq=1)
I was able to filter with contextual filter based on php query for current user